# Delete files existing in another directory tree

Tags: windows, cygwin

Maybe it's duplicate to [How to delete files in a directory, that exist in another directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/330241/how-to-delete-files-in-a-directory-that-exist-in-another-directory), but I need to consider also path. I just successfully repaired MBR and partition table, now I'm trying to recover on FS level, but the utility "recovers" also the healthy ones. So I want to delete them. Thanks

It might be my bad english, but I need to keep only files with different relative pathname in whole tree. Never mind, the new Beyond Compare can show also same files, not only different ones.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate. What's so difficult in replacing A and B with your folder names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete files in a directory, that exist in another directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/330241/how-to-delete-files-in-a-directory-that-exist-in-another-directory)